# Styled components - Object doesn't support property or method 'ToString'

Tags: styled-components

I am repeatedly getting this error in styled-components:
TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'ToString'

`styled-components/dist/styled-components.browser.esm.js" line 170 col 1`

So the error seems to be occurring in the package itself rather than in my codebase. I've tried updating to the latest version (3.4.5) of styled components and am still getting the same issue.

It seems to occur in mostly quite old browsers (eg Edge 13) but seems like that is recent enough to still be supported.

I can't find any reference to others having the same issue, so feel like it I may have used it wrong, but can't think what.

Comment: Can you show the styled element that is triggering this error? I have seen this error before in the event that I have a styled component declaration but no actual styles. Something like const box = styled.div``;